# failed redirect after mailing send and not send mail

Tags: php, mysql, smtp, phpmailer

```
<?php
include_once('admin/dbcon.php');
if(isset($_POST["submit"])=="Apply Now")
{  
   //$resume='';
   //$photos='';
    $fullname = strip_tags($_POST["fullname"]); 
    $address = strip_tags($_POST["address"]);   
    $state = strip_tags($_POST["state"]);   
    $city = strip_tags($_POST["city"]); 
    $mobile = strip_tags($_POST["mobile"]); 
    $email = strip_tags($_POST["email"]);   
    $username="xxxxxxx";
    $apply_for = strip_tags($_POST["apply_for"]);   
    /*Resume file uploaded*/
        $allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx"); 
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["up_resume"]["name"]));
        if ($_FILES["up_resume"]["type"] == "application/pdf" || 
            $_FILES["up_resume"]["type"] == "application/msword" || 
            $_FILES["up_resume"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
        {     
        $type =substr($_FILES["up_resume"]["name"],strrpos($_FILES["up_resume"]["name"], '.') + 1);
        $resume = "Resume_".time().".".$type;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["up_resume"]["tmp_name"], "admin/upload/".$resume); 
        }
        else
        {
        header("Location:apply-now.php?rm=Invalid file, Please upload your updated resume!!");
        }       
    /*Photo uploaded here*/
       $allowedExts1 = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $extension1 = end(explode(".", $_FILES["profiel_photos"]["name"]));
        if ($_FILES["profiel_photos"]["type"] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["profiel_photos"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" ||   
            $_FILES["profiel_photos"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["profiel_photos"]["type"] == "image/png" || $_FILES["profiel_photos"]["type"] == "image/jpg" )
        {      
        $type1 =substr($_FILES["profiel_photos"]["name"],strrpos($_FILES["profiel_photos"]["name"], '.') + 1);
        $photos = "prf_img_".time().".".$type1;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profiel_photos"]["tmp_name"], "admin/upload/".$photos); 
        }
        else
        {
        header("Location:apply-now.php?pic=Invalid file,Please upload your updated photos!!");
        }
     $status = "INSERT INTO `caretel`.`tb_career` (`FullName`, `Address`, `State`, `City`, `ContactNo`, `Email`, `Resume`, `ProfileImg`, `ApplyFor`) VALUES ('$fullname', '$address', '$state', '$city', '$mobile', '$email', '$resume', '$photos', '$apply_for')";
   if(mysql_query($status))
    {
     require_once('include/class.phpmailer.php');
     $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // 
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                    
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                 
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
        $mail->Port       = 25;                    
        $mail->Username   = "XXXXXX@gmail.com"; 
        $mail->Password   = "XXXXXXX";        
        //$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

       $mail->AddAddress($email,"Guest");
       $mail->SetFrom("cCXXXXXXX@gmail.com","XXXXXXXX");
       $mail->Subject = "New Applicat Applyed for ".$apply_for; 

       $body = 'html';

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->AddAttachment("admin/upload/".$resume);      // attachment
    $mail->AddAttachment("admin/upload/".$photos); // attachment

    if($mail->Send())
    {  
       echo "hi";
        header("Location:apply-now.php?msg=Thank you for Apply. We will be in touch with you very soon!!");

        exit;

    }else{

        header("Location:apply-now.php?msg=We encountered an error sending your mail");

        exit;
        }    
    }
 }else{
 echo "dfsdfsdfsdf ";
 }

?>
```

Mail not sending and not redirect to apply-now.php pages i also us port with ssl 465 and tls 587 and not showing any kind of error after mail sending only redirect on my action php page ,  what is problem in this code please help me 
Thanks

Comment: Load PHPMailer by loading its autoloader, not the class (and make sure you're using the latest version). To diagnose this, sort out your sending before using redirects - they tend to prevent you seeing debug output. For gmail you should definitely be using tls on 587. If you're going to use debug output, I suggest you set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` to get a more complete picture of what's happening.

Comment: You should probably break down your script into parts and test them independently (functions or classes). For example test the mailer with dummy data. Test the redirection by itself. Test the form submission with no attachments and finally everything together. I suggest using a library like Symfony2\HttpFoundation to handle the request and redirection, and SwiftMailer to send emails. These libraries are well maintained and documented. Finally use parametrized queries to write data to your database, the way you are currently doing it will enable anyone to perform SQL injections attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending this out, we have to modify the PHPMailer object to indicate that the message should be interpreted as HTML. Technically-speaking, the message body has to be set up as multipart/alternative. This is done with:

**$mail->IsHTML(true);**

For more information you can [visit here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Not necessary: `msgHTML()` sets that for you.